# PHPexcel can't save file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a file where I want to use standart example.
Like [here](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) , but I added `php://output` instead of `str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__)` because I want file to be downloaded by user.
So, I have a form:

```
$res.="<form method='POST' action='".$this->self()."'>";
$res.="<input type='text' class='span5' placeholder='Address' name='excelAddress'></input>";
$res.="<button type='submit' id='export' class='span2 pull-right'>Экспорт</button>";
$res.="</form>";
```

And if `post['excelAddress']` isset I try standart example:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Administrator");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Administrator");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Показания клиентов по адресу:".$_POST['excelAddress']);
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Показания клиентов по адресу:".$_POST['excelAddress']);
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Показания клиентов по адресу:".$_POST['excelAddress']);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Also in the top of my page I have includes:

```
/** PHPExcel */
include './lib/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include './lib/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
```

Also I have there:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Do I need:

```
/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');
```

Or it just not to write ./lib./... where I have all libs?
When I try my example I just have:

```
KL�,EG�D�X�[Content_Types].xml��MN�0���"�%nY ��vAa  �(0����ؖg�w{&i�@�nbE�{��y��d۸l m������X�(���)���F���;@1_������c)j�x/%��E��y� �QĿi!��K�y3�J<���Z1�0?Y�L%zV c��Ib7�����a/l٥P1:�q�r��j��j0A����u�""���(�   ���W�M��)Tj�({ܲ�>�O��,X٭���>B��~׭���Ӥ6�J=�oBZ����t��X4���Cg�,���QgmrL�ٯc�e���t��    Z�?����hPv��±��u�j���R�������}�Cv��PKL�,E�78�K_rels/.rels���j�0��{ �{���1F�^ʠ�2��l��$���-}�y����Î��O��v�y�;�؋Ӱ.JP���޵^������Yű�3G�Ww�g)����>�qQC��D����b!�]�i$L��3����2n���oT�:Z �h�����[��4�ი��]��yN�,ە�>�>�j -' V�)�#��EF^6��n���8q"K��H��>_ׄ����eƏ�<⇄�Ud�v�� T�PKL�,E�$�V��xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels���j�0D�� ��ZvZJ)�s)�\[����LlIh7m��UH��Ĭؙ�H���8�OL���*J�M���|4��g��[=�
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Try setting an Content-Type header, then it might display as an Excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you forgot to add `header`.

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

In addition headers are for :

**.xls**: application/vnd.ms-excel

**.xlsx**: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: It says that format or file extension is not valid. I try variant for xlsx.

Comment: `It` being? MS Excel? In that case, make sure that your script has no echoed whitespace characters or anything after  a closing `?>` (even better, remove any closing `?>`)

Comment: I ried ms excel variant and it works. But with strange simbols there with document too. Gonna find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send the http response headers so that the browser knows how to handle the data that is being sent to it. Take a look at `/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php`